# How to configure AutoMapper to handle a type conversion only in a specific scenario?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following objects:

```cs
public enum DomainEnum
{
    FooFoo = 1,
    BarBaz,
}

public class DomainEntity
{
    public DomainEnum DomainEnum { get; set; }
}

public class DataAccessEntity
{
    public string ActuallyAnEnum { get; set; }
}

public static class DomainDataAccessEnumConverter
{
    public static string Map(DomainEnum domainEnum)
    {
        switch (domainEnum)
        {
            case DomainEnum.FooFoo: return "COMPUTER";
            case DomainEnum.BarBaz: return "SAYSNO";
            default: throw ...
        }
    }

    public static DomainEnum Map(string domainEnumString)
    {
        switch (domainEnumString.ToUpper())
        {
            case "COMPUTER": return DomainEnum.FooFoo;
            case "SAYSNO": return DomainEnum.BarBaz;
            default: throw ...
        }
    }
}
```

I've setup AutoMapper so that these objects automatically convert between each other:

```cs
CreateMap<string, DomainEnum>()
    .ConvertUsing(s => DomainDataAccessEnumConverter.Map(s));

CreateMap<DomainEnum, string>()
    .ConvertUsing(d => DomainDataAccessEnumConverter.Map(d));

CreateMap<DataAccessEntity, DomainEntity>()
    .ReverseMap();
```

This now permits implicit conversion between `string` and `DomainEnum` from anywhere in the application. However it doesn't make sense to perform this conversion in any context other than when mapping between `DataAccessEntity` and `DomainEntity`, so I'd prefer it if this mapping was only used in that scenario - for everything else I want the standard .NET conversions to happen (and throw an exception in the `string` to `DomainEnum` case).

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-converters.html

Answer (score -1):

```js
 var d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            d.Add("COMPUTER", 1);
            d.Add("SAYSNO", 2);
            var t1 = from k in d
                     select new
                     {
                         values = DomainDataAccessEnumConverter.Map(k.Key)
                     };
```